# scss nesting stuck with syntax and nesting

Tags: html, css, sass

i'm trying to learn Sass - Can some help me convert the following to scss, I'm totally stuck on how to nest this one ?
Is it possible to tidy up the code? I've tried a few combinations that didn't work, I've also looked at the documentation to no avail

```
ul.related li, .sidebar p {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #999;
  color: #07A;
  font-size: 0.92em;
  margin-top: 0.4em;
  text-align: center;

}

ul.related li:last-child {
  border-bottom: none;
}


.sidebar p {
  border-bottom: none;
}



ul.related {
  width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: SO is not a code optimizer/linter service.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For bestpractice  remove the common style in to a placeholder and extend it.

```
%commonstyle {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #999;
    color: #07A;
    font-size: 0.92em;
    margin-top: 0.4em;
    text-align: center;
}

ul.related {
    width: 100%;
    li {
        @extend %commonstyle;
        &:last-child {
            border-bottom: none;
        }
    }
}
.sidebar p {
    @extend %commonstyle;
    border-bottom: none;
}
```

Comment: thanks kiran, i would have never have got that ....